# How to flatten json and then join to another table, enrich and aggregate back to json using flink sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have data from `table1` in 2 columns `id` and `access` (this is json array). This is built using kafka connector

```
{
  "id": "8250bccd3b4249868e24bda491a2aa8e",
  "access": [
    {
      "id": "entitlement-id-1",
      "type": "ENTITLEMENT",
    },
    {
      "id": "entitlement-id-2",
      "type": "ENTITLEMENT",
    },
    {
      "id": "role-id-1",
      "type": "ROLE",
    }
  ]
}
```

Question 1:
How to flatten the `access` column by filtering out only `type=ENTITLEMENT`  .

later on I want to join the `access.id` with data from another table named `table2`, sample data

```
{
  "id": "entitlement-id-1",
  "otherData": "any number of fields"
}
```

and produce a final result as below. Here the `access` is aggregated back to json array.

```
{
  "id": "8250bccd3b4249868e24bda491a2aa8e",
  "access": [
    {
      "id": "entitlement-id-1",
      "type": "ENTITLEMENT",
      "otherData": "any number of fields"
    },
    {
      "id": "entitlement-id-2",
      "type": "ENTITLEMENT",
      "otherData": null
    },
    {
      "id": "role-id-1",
      "type": "ROLE",
      "otherData": null
    }
  ]
}
```